# Replacing Failed Boot Disk

Tags: boot, ssd, drive

I have a current Ubuntu system that boots from a solid state drive. This drive only has the boot partition and nothing else. The main files including /home and / are located on a RAID 5 array.

It has been working well for some time. Recently, the boot drive developed smart errors and the system would not update using apt-get. 
Since the drive is failing and booting is a 1 in three chance, I have purchased a replacement SSD drive to use to boot.

I have been trying to find a walkthrough that will show me how to install the boot files on the new virgin drive while retaining access to my RAID array. I don't want to lose access as rebuilding it would be a real chore as the array is 19 terabytes!

Of course, booting from the raid array would be the smarter way to go, but I need a stable system before I can even attempt that bit of wizardry. 
Any help or pointers to a walkthrough would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck using Clonezilla. The last time I checked it was available on Sourceforge.
It can clone individual partitions or entire drives, which sounds like what you want.
You may need to use the "recover" option if errors are encountered during the cloning process.

BTW, it will do a physical <-> physical or a physical <-> disk image clone. The target drive/partition will need to be at least as large as the source.

There are other options, but explaining them would require knowing whether the drive uses a GPT or MBR partitioning scheme. Clonezilla can handle either.

Good luck,
ron

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this, however, I am concerned that with the damage to the boot drive, I may only transfer the problem to the new drive. Is there any way to re-install the boot partition, yet still retain access to my /home and / partitions?

Comment: That depends on whether or not you have a relatively current backup of your system's /boot directory. You didn't mention that you have backups. Smart errors are at a much lower level in the stack. If the system runs properly when it DOES boot, you've got a reasonable chance of the cloning process working without file corruption. If you can successfully create a tar archive of your /boot directory, I can walk you through the steps to make a boot partition (with grub installed) on a new drive.